# Retonor Ajax, Json em PHP

Tags: php, ajax, json

como pego o retorno e coloco dentro de uma variavel php exemplo: vamos dizer que estou retornado o id do usuario e queria que este id estivesse dentro do $id para que possa ser feito um link ">nome se poder alguem me ajudar muito grato.

index.php

```
   <html lang="pt-br">  
   <head>  
   <meta charset="utf-8">  
   <title>titulo</title>  
   <link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>  
   <script 
  src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"> 
  </script>  
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">  
   $(document).ready(function() {  
   $('#listar-usuario').DataTable({             
      "processing": true,  
      "serverSide": true,  
      "ajax": {  
      "url": "proc_pesq_user.php",  
      "type": "POST"  
    }  
  });  
    } );  
</script>  
</head>  
<body>  
Listar usuários
<table id="listar-usuario" class="display" style="width:100%">  
   <thead>
   <tr>
   <th><a href="pagina.php?usuario=<?php echo $id;?>">Codigo</a></th>
   <th>Nome</th>
   <th>celular</th>
</tr>  
</thead>  
</table>    
</body>  
</html>
```

proc_pesq_user.php

```
<?php  
   header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8",true);  
   $servername = "localhost";  
   $username = "root";  
   $password = "010203";  
   $dbname = "banco";  
   $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);  
   $conn->set_charset("utf8");  
   $requestData= $_REQUEST;  
  //Indice da coluna na tabela visualizar resultado => idservidor da coluna 
  no banco de dados  
  $columns = array(  
  0 =>'idservidor',  
  1 => 'nome',  
  2=> 'celular'  
  );  
  //Obtendo registros de número total sem qualquer pesquisa  
  $result_user = "SELECT idservidor, nome, celular FROM servidor";  
  $resultado_user =mysqli_query($conn, $result_user);  
  $qnt_linhas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_user); 
  //Obter os dados a serem apresentados  
  $result_usuarios = "SELECT idservidor, nome, celular FROM servidor WHERE 
  1=1";  
  if( !empty($requestData['search']['value']) ) {   // se houver um 
  parâmetro de pesquisa, 
  $requestData['search']['value'] contém o parâmetro de pesquisa  
  $result_usuarios.=" AND ( idservidor LIKE '".$requestData['search'] 
  ['value']."%' ";  
  $result_usuarios.=" OR nome LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";  
  $result_usuarios.=" OR celular LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%'  
  )";  
}
  $resultado_usuarios=mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuarios);  
  $totalFiltered = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_usuarios); 

  //Ordenar o resultado  

  $result_usuarios.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0] 
  ['column']]."     ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT 
  ".$requestData['start']." 
  ,".$requestData['length']."   ";  
  $resultado_usuarios=mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuarios);  
  // Ler e criar o array de dados  
  $dados = array();  
  while( $row_usuarios =mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_usuarios) ) {  
     $dado = array();  
    $dado[] = $row_usuarios["idservidor"];  
    $dado[] = $row_usuarios["nome"];  
    $dado[] = $row_usuarios["celular"];  
    $dados[] = $dado;  
 }  
//Cria o array de informações a serem retornadas para o Javascript  
   $json_data = array(  
   "draw" => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),//para cada requisição é enviado 
    um número como parâmetro
    "recordsTotal" => intval( $qnt_linhas ),  //Quantcelular de registros 
    que há no banco de dados  
    "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), //Total de registros 
    quando houver pesquisa  
    "data" => $dados   //Array de dados completo dos dados retornados da 
    tabela
   );  
    echo json_encode($json_data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | 
    JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);  
   //enviar dados como formato json  
  ?>
```

Comment: De onde vem o $id? Qual id deseja pegar? É enviado por um formulário?

Comment: O id vem da pagina proc_pesq_user.php como json, na verdade um array de três campos   0 =>'idservidor',  
  1 => 'nome',   
  2=> 'celular'  esses tres campos preenche a tabela datatable na pagina  
 index.php bem aqui nesse trecho <table id="listar-usuario" class="display" style="width:100%">  
   <thead>  
   <tr>
   <th><a href="pagina.php?usuario=<?php echo $id;?>">Codigo</a></th>
   <th>Nome</th>  
   <th>celular</th>  
</tr>    
</thead>    
</table>  e no campo codigo eu quero fazer um link passando o $id , só não consigo recuperar o json e jogar nesse $id.